# How can I programmatically remove recent files from Quick Access in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, powershell

From time to time I'll open a file for which I don't want to retain an entry in the Recent Files section of Quick Access.

How can I automate the removal of these entries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this by creating a Scheduled Task that runs a PowerShell script at a given interval. The script clears these items according to certain criteria, in this case if the file contains the text "Unwanted" anywhere in its path.

Example:

```
$Namespace = "shell:::{679f85cb-0220-4080-b29b-5540cc05aab6}"
$QuickAccess = New-Object -ComObject shell.application
$RecentFiles = $QuickAccess.Namespace($Namespace).Items()
$FilteredFiles = $RecentFiles | ? {$_.Path -like "*Unwanted*"}
$FilteredFiles | % {$_.InvokeVerb("remove")}
```